# How can I loop through a file and output its contents to a file in a new directory without the same extension?

Tags: for

Quite a basic question but I am new to this.

Example: Within my current directory, I have the folder looptest containing file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt

I wish to output their contents to the folder looptest_out into new files called file1.txt.test.txt, etc. (assuming I do not try to remove the extension)

So I tried the code:

```
for FILE in looptest/*; do cat $FILE > looptest_out/"$FILE.test.txt"; done
```

I get the following error:

```
testing_loops: line 17: looptest_out/looptest/file1.txt.test.txt: No such file or directory
testing_loops: line 17: looptest_out/looptest/file2.txt.test.txt: No such file or directory
testing_loops: line 17: looptest_out/looptest/file3.txt.test.txt: No such file or directory
```

I think the problem is that $FILE keeps the extension of the directory the file is in, so it ends up looking for the directory looptest_out/looptest , which does not exist (both those folders are in my current directory)

So basically, I need to just get the file name without the directory, and use that as the stem for the new name of my file. And I would also like to know how to remove the ".txt" from the end if possible. I tried doing things with `"${file##*/}"` and  `"${file%.txt}".test.txt` but it ended up just giving a blank name.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why `cat` when you can `cp`? Also, your quotation marks should go around the full name, like `"looptest_out/${FILE}.test.txt"

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK I changed both of those but the output was the same

Comment: so, why not simply `cd looptest;` and then `for FILE in *; do cp $FILE ../looptest_out/$FILE.suffix;done`?

Comment: @Brassicka Assuming you have reasons for using `cat` instead of copying (`cp`) or moving (renaming) your files, you were on the right track. You may want to edit your question and show how you used `"${file##*/}"` and `"${file%.txt}".test.txt` (the exact commands), they may just need some adjustment.

Comment: If you are new to BASH you might investigate the `basename` command. It's not as clever as "${file##*/}" and "${file%.txt}" - but you only need to strip the '.txt' thing.

Comment: @JeremyBoden Nice, that looks useful! I'll give it a go